# Integration test for RESTful Web Service

Tags: java, integration-testing, h2

This is my integration test controller class. Method get all team and there was a problem with compilation:

```
@SpringJUnitWebConfig(classes = CrewApplication.class)
public class Team_Controller_Integration_Test {
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception
{
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
void getAccount() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/teams")
            .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$version").value(null))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$name").value("Apacze"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$createOn").value(null))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("modifiedOn").value(null))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$description").value("grupa programistow"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$city").value("Włocławek"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$headcount").value(null));
}
```

}

This is my error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

On the other hand I create test for Db adn I have problem becouse after add mock elements to db they return null:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class Team_database_integration_test {

    @MockBean
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

    @Test
    public void testDb(){
        Team team = new Team(1L,"teamName","teamDescription","krakow",7);
        testEntityManager.persist(team);
        testEntityManager.flush();

        System.out.println(team);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the below solution!

Comment: Yes i try today morning. I have java.lang.NullPointerException :/

Comment: I edit this post and show U how my test look's like now

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency declaration to test case

```
@Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
```

and correct the  initialization

```
@Before
    public void setup() throws Exception
    {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
```

try changing  to this signature,i think content type is by default -json.Try without assertions first then add assertions for validations!

```
MvcResult CDTO = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/plan/1"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andReturn();
```